# The script is not skipping the lines mentioned in my skip list

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a very simple python script that must apply some changes in my input txt file
for example my input txt file is:

```
ari2600
ARI
304,975
nnelun
CHALF185,406
Magnassey
PHPS119,353
dioI
69,671
ari5200
ARI
0
ari7800
ARI
0
assesion
EPOCH0
Coleion
QUECO0
Gatch
Nido®
0
Mavsion
MEL
0
NESSD
Ndo®
0
SG-1000
SAO
Sestem
SEO
1978Q2
```

and my skip list is:

```
ari2600
nnelun
Magnassey
dioI
ari5200
ari7800
assesion
Coleion
Gatch
Mavsion
NESSD
SG-1000
Sestem
```

script must check **each line of my input txt file** and each line must **exclude my skip list lines**.
after that if checked line exclude my skip list then script must apply following find & replace on that line and if checked line include my skip list then must skip that line and no need any changes.

```
find what : ^(?!\d{4}Q[1-4])([^\d\n]+)([\d,]+)
replace : \r\n$&
```

my python script is:

```
import re

# Define the input file path
file_path = r'E:\Desktop\edit1\joined.txt'

# Pattern to match lines to be skipped
skip_pattern = r'G:\\NOW\\joined.txt'

# Pattern for finding and replacing in non-skipped lines
find_pattern = r'^(?!\d{4}Q[1-4])([^\d\n]+)([\d,]+)'
replace_pattern = r'\r\n$&'

# Read file, check each line, and modify accordingly
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

modified_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if re.search(skip_pattern, line):
        # Skip lines matching the skip pattern
        modified_lines.append(line)
    else:
        # Modify lines that don't match the skip pattern
        modified_line = re.sub(find_pattern, replace_pattern, line)
        modified_lines.append(modified_line)

# Write modified lines back to the file
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(modified_lines)
```

**my script working but it have a problem!**, it doesn't skip my skip list
**for example it not skip ari2600** and convert it to following result by regex:

```
ari
2600
```

where is my script problem?

Comment: `re.search(skip_pattern, line)` currently is trying to look at the pattern in the variable skip_pattern (which is a file path, and not an actual pattern of different texts to skip over). You may want to load in the file to have the various skip patterns to search through -- or just insert the single skip pattern into the `skip_pattern` variable

Comment: You are replacing with `\r\n$&` but you will match 2 capture groups. Why not replace with `r'\1\n\2`

Comment: @Thefourthbird it remove 2600 from ari2600 !!

Comment: @PubgMobile Do you want to replace with the full match like `replace_pattern = r'\n\g<0>'` ? Then you also do not need capture groups in the regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes it working but script still have main problem and not skipping my skip list!

Comment: I'm not understand what you mean about modified_list! please write a sample or re-write script that I learn problem

Answer (score 0):

tnq everyone that tried to help for this problem
I fixed problem by following script:

```
import re

def separate_alphanumeric(line):
    matches = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+|\D+', line)
    return matches

input_file_path = r'E:\Desktop\joined - Copy.txt'
output_file_path = r'E:\Desktop\formatted_output.txt'
skip_values_file_path = r'E:\Desktop\nnnnn.txt'

# Regex pattern to skip certain lines
skip_pattern = re.compile(r'\d{4}Q[1-4]')

# Load skip values from nnnnn.txt
with open(skip_values_file_path, 'r') as skip_file:
    skip_values = set(line.strip() for line in skip_file)

# Process the input file
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file, open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if skip_pattern.search(line):
            output_file.write(line + '\n\n')  # Write skipped line with spacing
        elif line not in skip_values:
            matches = separate_alphanumeric(line)
            for match in matches:
                output_file.write(match + '\n')
        else:
            output_file.write(line + '\n\n')  # Skip value, add two newlines for spacing
```